# Projective representation of $\mathbb{Z}_N\times\mathbb{Z}_N$ by $su(N)$ generators

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

[The same question has been posted in MathStackExchange.]

The projective representation (rep.) of $\mathbb{Z}_N\times\mathbb{Z}_N$ is $\mathbb{Z}_N$-classified. 
It can be understood by embedding into a $SU(N)$ representation.

For example, taking $N=2$, the nontrivial projective rep. of $\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2$ can be written by: 
\begin{eqnarray}
V=\exp(i\pi S^x);\,\,\,W=\exp(i\pi S^z), 
\end{eqnarray}
where $S^x=\sigma_1/2$ and $S^z=\sigma_3/2$ with Pauli matrices $\vec{\sigma}$ in the fundamental representation (namely spin-$1/2$ rep.). 
The projective nature is characterized by their commutator
\begin{eqnarray}
VWV^{-1}W^{-1}=-1. 
\end{eqnarray}
For general spin-$s$ rep., we have $VWV^{-1}W^{-1}=(-1)^{2s}$, which is $\mathbb{Z}_2$-classified by $2s$ mod $2$.

My question is whether there is any explicit $\mathbb{Z}_N\times\mathbb{Z}_N$ treatment like above. 
In other words, can we explicitly write down
\begin{eqnarray}
V_N=\exp(iT_V);\,\,W_N=\exp(iT_W), 
\end{eqnarray}
with two certain $T_V$ and $T_W$ in Lie algebra $su(N)$, so that for the fundamental rep., we have
\begin{eqnarray}
V_NW_NV_N^{-1}W_N^{-1}=\exp\left(i\frac{2\pi}{N}\right). 
\end{eqnarray}
For instance, can we write down explicitly $T_V$ and $T_W$ in a certain $su(N)$ basis?

Comment: Crossposted from https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3696798/11127

Comment: [Related](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/66124/relations-between-diffeomorphism-symmetry-theories-and-invariant-sun-n-righ), and, [further](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/9641/weyl-exponential-form-of-the-canonical-commutation-relations).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is closely related to the matrices described in

> Patera, J. and Zassenhaus, H., 1988. The Pauli matrices in n
>   dimensions and finest gradings of simple Lie algebras of type $A_{n− 1}$.
>   Journal of mathematical physics, 29(3), pp.665-673.

For $\mathfrak{su}(2)$, these are the regular Pauli matrices (up to a phase) and they are labelled by elements in $\mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_2$.  To be explicit:
\begin{align}
\sigma_1&=\left(\begin{array}{cc} 0&1\\ -1 &0\end{array}\right)
\to \sigma_{(1,0)}\, , \\
\sigma_2&=\left(\begin{array}{cc} 0&i\\ -i &0\end{array}\right)\to \sigma_{(1,1)}\, , \\
\sigma_3&=\left(\begin{array}{cc} i&0\\ 0 &-i\end{array}\right) \to \sigma_{(0,1)}\, ,\\
\sigma_0&=\left(\begin{array}{cc} 1&0\\ 0 &1\end{array}\right)\to \sigma_{(0,0)}\
\end{align}
These matrices are proportional to the Pauli matrices and are also unitary.

The commutation relations are of the form
\begin{align}
[\sigma_{(p,q)},\sigma_{(p',q')}]= k \sigma_{(p+p',q+q')}
\end{align}
where $k=\pm$ depending on $(p,q)$ and $(p',q')$  and 
addition is taken mod 2.

The $8$ matrices $\pm \sigma_k$ form a subgroup of $SU(2)$ (under multiplication of course) and thus, if you just use the set of $\sigma_k$, you get what you want.

The nice thing about the P&Z paper is they generalize this to any $\mathfrak{su}(n)$.  For $n=3$, the generalized Pauli matrices are generate by products of 
\begin{align}
A=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 1 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)\to\sigma_{(0,-1)}\, ,\qquad 
D=
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & \omega  & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & \omega ^2 \\
\end{array}
\right)\to \sigma_{(1,0)}
\end{align}
where $\omega^3=1$.   A total of 27 matrices can be obtained by multiplication of these generating elements.  They do satisfy in general
\begin{align}
X_kY_{k'}X_k^{-1} Y_{k}^{-1}= \omega^j 
\end{align}
for some power of $\omega$.  Moreover, under commutation they also satisfy $[X_{k},X_{k'}]=\omega^{j'} X_{k+k'}$ where $k+k'$ is taken modulo $3$ in each entry.  A subset of $8$ of these, plus the identity, spans the $\mathfrak{su}(3)$ algebra.  Note that the matrices are (of course) not hermitian.

Unfortunately, they are not given the form $V_N=\exp(i T_V)$ although presumably this can be worked out by expanding $T_V$ in terms of the $8$ elements chosen as basis set for $\mathfrak{su}(3)$, plus $\mathbb{1}$.

Comment: Many thanks for the reminder! The permutation matrix and the diagonal one do the job!

Comment: @SmartYao It's not even permutation & diagonal -- it's right-shift and diag(1,x,x^2,...) for x the N'th root.  These do the job most of the time when you want to diagonalize Pauli matrices!

Comment: @SmartYao the paper by P&Z is really cool, and Patera followed up with Patera, J., 1989. The four sets of additive quantum numbers of SU (3). Journal of mathematical physics, 30(12), pp.2756-2762, which is equally cool.  His group did a lot of work exploring this afterwards but it was more mathematically oriented.

Comment: Thanks for the reference!

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this is the exponential Weyl form of the Heisenberg group commutation relations, through [bounded, unitary operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93von_Neumann_theorem#Uniqueness_of_representation), of utility in the Stone-von Neumann theorem,  $\exp\left[\frac{i}{\hbar} Q \hat{p}~\right] \exp\left[\frac{i}{\hbar}P\hat{q}~\right]$ $= e^{iPQ/\hbar}
\exp\left[\frac{i}{\hbar}P\hat{q}~\right]\exp\left[\frac{i}{\hbar} Q \hat{p}~\right]$.

Weyl, in his celebrated book, illustrates this structure in "quantum mechanics around the clock" (of *N* hours), utilizing [Sylvester's clock and shift matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalizations_of_Pauli_matrices#Construction:_The_clock_and_shift_matrices) limiting to elements of the Heisenberg group at large *N*.

Specifically, as Sylvester defined them in 1882 and Weyl used them in 1927, the clock *N×N* matrix $V\sim \Sigma_3$ and the discrete shift matrix $W\sim \Sigma_1$ braid to
$$
\Sigma_3 \Sigma _1= e^{2\pi i /N} \Sigma_1 \Sigma _3,
$$
in a clock of *N* hours. They generalize the Pauli matrices $\sigma_3, \sigma_1$, for $\omega= \exp(2\pi i/N)$,
$$
\Sigma _1 =
\begin{bmatrix}
0           & 0 & 0      & \cdots &0 & 1\\
1           & 0 & 0      & \cdots & 0 & 0\\
0           & 1 & 0      & \cdots & 0 & 0\\
0      & 0     & 1 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
\vdots      & \vdots     & \vdots & \ddots &\vdots &\vdots \\
0           & 0     &0   & \cdots    & 1 & 0\\ 
\end{bmatrix} \\\Sigma _3 =
\begin{bmatrix}
1      & 0         & 0 & \cdots & 0\\
0      & \omega    & 0 & \cdots & 0\\
0      & 0         &\omega ^2 & \cdots & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots    & \vdots    & \ddots & \vdots\\
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & \omega ^{N-1}
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

These and their products and powers comprise a set of $N^2$ independent  *U(N)* group matrices, which, coincidentally, may *further* serve as a basis of the *su(N) algebra*, your concern here.  (The perfect "analytic" basis for *su(N)* with ***trigonometric*** structure constants, reviewed [here](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/1.528788). Yes, this Sylvester basis preceded the Gell-Mann basis by 80 years).

If you wished to take their logarithms, this has also been done,  cleverly, by use of the discrete Fourier transform, by [Santhanam & Tekumalla](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF00715110), but the "momentum" exponent is a [bit of a mess](https://www.hep.anl.gov/czachos/exam.pdf); do you understand why? It still does the job, and illustrates a mystifying aspect of the tracelessness of the commutator of the exponents in a finite space.