# Multiplying $X$ and $P$ operators in quantum mechanics using delta functions (on the $X$ basis)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, dirac-delta-distributions

Alright so I'm trying to figure out how to find the operator $XP$ in the $x$ basis, knowing that the elements of $X$ and $P$ are $x \delta(x-x')$ and $-ih \delta'(x-x')$ respectively. I know how to do it by assuming $X=x$ and $P=-ihd/dx$, but I don't want to do it that way, I want to actually calculate the elements of the new matrix. Now normally I would assume I just have to multiply the $xx'$ element of $X$ with the $x'x$ element of $P$ and then integrate over $x'$, analogous to how I would multiply two finite matrices. However I would then end up with an integral over $x'$ which contains two delta functions, $\delta(x-x')$ and $\delta'(x'-x)$. I have no idea how to integrate that. I believe there is a gap in my understanding of infinite matrices, delta functions, etc. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Could you write out the integral you're having trouble with in your question?

Comment: Well, I could try but it definitely seems wrong to me. I'm on a mobile so writing it in detail seems a bit hard now, I simply tried to integrate over x' the product of the elements Xxx' and Px'x as I described them above.

Answer (score 3):

How about using momentum eigenstates as the states being summed over:
$$
\langle x|\hat x\hat p|x'\rangle=
\int \frac{dp}{2\pi} \langle x|\hat x|p\rangle   \langle{p}|\hat p|x'\rangle \\
= \int \frac{dp}{2\pi} x e^{ipx} p e^{-ip x'}\\
= x \int \frac{dp}{2\pi} e^{ipx} i\frac{\partial}{\partial x'}  e^{-ip x'}\\
ix\frac{\partial}{\partial x'} \int \frac{dp}{2\pi} e^{ip(x-x')}  \\
= ix\frac{\partial}{\partial x'} \delta(x-x')\\
=- ix\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\delta(x-x')
$$
It's not exactly rigorous mathematics, but it   makes me less nervous that multiplying two distributions!

Comment: I thought about that but it's kinda what I wanted to avoid. I wanted to understand how I could multiply two infinite matrices in some sort of rigorous manner. Also where did that 2pi denominator come from?

Comment: The  $2\pi$ is just my normalization of $|p\rangle$: $\langle p|p'\rangle= 2\pi \delta(p-p')$. There's no way to define $\hat x$ so that both it and $\hat p$ turn into infinite discrete matrices.  $\hat x$ is undefined in a periodic  system, and with rigid walls $\hat p$ is not self adjoint.

Comment: Oooh alright thanks, I missed that.

Comment: @AndreasC that integral *is* analogous to matrix multiplication. It's almost exactly the same as writing out $A  = B \cdot C$ as $A_{ij} = \sum_k B_{ik}C_{kj}$.

Comment: Which integral?

Answer (score 3):

The dirty secret here is that not all operators are infinite-dimensional "matrices" (the ones that are in a reasonable sense are [Hilbert-Schmidt operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%E2%80%93Schmidt_operator) but $x$ and $p$ are not among them) and that $\lvert x\rangle$ and $\lvert p\rangle$ are not elements of the Hilbert space (but instead of a larger rigged Hilbert space, see [user1504's excellent answer on the topic](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/43519/50583)). The operators $x$ and $p$ simply can't both act on things like $\lvert x\rangle$ in a well-defined manner, because they are far outside the domain of definition for $p$.

As you noticed, in this case pretending these things are ordinary matrices and vectors lands you in the ill-defined world of products of distributions. They are not, and you cannot blindly apply naive generalizations of finite-dimensional linear algebra to them. You already know the correct way to represent $xp$, namely by taking $p$ as the derivative operator. Just do that if you're looking for rigor and sanity.

Comment: Oh wow, have I been lied to? Lots of textbooks make it sound like you can do that... Huh. Do you know any books or material that I can read on this subject? I want to understand the mathematics behind QM a bit better and more rigorously because I feel like I don't have a great grasp and a lot of things seem really hand wavy or misleading... That's the whole reason I tried to do what I tried to do here, I thought, hey, the textbooks pretend it's all infinite dimensional matrices etc, can't I just multiply their elements?

Comment: Oh lol I just noticed the post you linked to answered a similar question...

Comment: Still, I'd appreciate some sort of neat little book that explores the math about QM and what you can and can't do.

Comment: @AndreasC It's not available as a "neat little book", it's basically the entire mathematical field of functional analysis. A classic for the physicist interested in rigor is the multi-volume series (!) by Simon and Reed.

Comment: Jesus Christ I just checked it lol. It's actually huge. Yeesh. Idk where to start now...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand the question, but Dirac's picture, in his landmark book, instructs you to
use
$$
\hat X = \int dx ~~|x\rangle x \langle x| ,\\
\hat P = \int dx ~~|x\rangle \frac{\hbar}{i}\partial_x \langle x| ,
$$
so
$$
\hat X \hat P = \int dx dx' ~~|x\rangle x \langle x   |x'\rangle \frac{\hbar}{i}\partial_{x'} \langle x'| = \int dx dx' ~~|x\rangle x ~ \delta ( x -x')  ~\frac{\hbar}{i}\partial_{x'} \langle x'| \\ = \frac{\hbar}{i} \int dx ~|x\rangle x  ~ \partial_{x} ~\langle x| ,
$$
which evokes your matrix multiplication vision.

The "matrix" vision is normally illustrated by "quantum mechanics around the clock, in a "clock" of *N* hours, expounded in Weyl's celebrated book, where you see that $\hat P$ (found by Santhanam & Tekumalla) is not diagonal, but, in a cagey/crafty large *N* limit devolves to the above (which is also really not diagonal).

Comment: Huh... That reminds me of something I actually did earlier on thinking it was just bullshit... Interesting to see it isn't but I was mostly concerned about why what I described in my original post didn't work. Still, your post is definitely helpful. Ευχαριστώ ;)

Comment: Link to [S&T](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/555647/projective-representation-of-mathbbz-n-times-mathbbz-n-by-sun-generat) is here. I can't do it myself, but I have watched RPF use "bullshit" to deadly effect.

Comment: What is RPF? Also, this is pretty interesting, I'll look into it.

Comment: Ooooh alright. Well, yeah, unsurprising. He got results though. 
My bullshit didn't map exactly to what you mentioned but it was kinda similar in concept. To be completely honest I don't remember exactly what I did... I did it a few days ago when that question first sprang into my mind and for a while I thought "yeah, that makes sense". Then today I thought "hold on" and started looking further into it. I remember I still used delta functions somehow but I integrated over what I called x and y, and somehow it gave the correct result for the few operators I tried it on...