# What is the correspond commutator of $[x,p]=i\hbar$ in lattice model?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, commutator, crystals

In lattice model, we can define $\hat x|n\rangle=n|n\rangle$, and $\hat p|k\rangle=k|k\rangle$, where $|k\rangle=\sum_ne^{ikn}|n\rangle$, but we cann't get $[\hat x,\hat p]|k\rangle=i|k\rangle$ for any $k$. So I want ask what the correspond commutator of $[x,p]=i$ in lattice model is.

Comment: $e^{ip}$ is the lattice translation $T$, so the analog of $[x,p]=i$ is $TxT^{-1}=x+1$.

Comment: That is interesting, it's very helpful, thanks a lot!  If there are some reference about this?

Comment: Santhanam, T.S., Tekumalla, A.R.,  [Quantum mechanics in finite dimensions, *Found Phys* **6**  (1976) 583–587](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF00715110), eqns (20-21). This is the standard [QM around the clock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalizations_of_Pauli_matrices#Construction:_The_clock_and_shift_matrices).

Comment: Look at Q10 of [this exam](https://www.hep.anl.gov/czachos/exam.pdf).

Comment: [Linked](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/555647/projective-representation-of-mathbbz-n-times-mathbbz-n-by-sun-generat).